# error when using Zend classes \ db \ sql \ select

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a problem when using Zend classes `db`, `sql` and `select`. My users table has 10 rows but returns results only 1 line.

File Model:

```
public function DbFetchAll ($ table) {
     try {
         $ select = $ this -> _ sql-> select ();
         $ Select-> from ($ table);
         $ statement = $ this -> _ sql-> prepareStatementForSqlObject ($ select);
         $ result = $ statement-> execute () -> current ();
         return $ result;
     } Catch (Exception $ exc) {
         echo $ exc-> getMessage ();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

`-> current ();` returning current pointing record. Try removing it. It should work.